# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index when trying to print an individual column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to print an individual column from the data frame that I am working on and the error I get is ...“TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index“ Below is an example of what I am trying to do

```
     country        Energy Supply     %Renewable
0    Afghanistan        321              77
1    Albania           102              100
2    Algeria           1959             0.6

df['country']
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

Comment: Please add the content of `df` or an example.

Comment: Please include a full [mcve] in text in your question, [not as a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), including the full error traceback and sample input

Comment: type(df) gives .... pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

Comment: Ah I see. I was able to look at the error message a bit in that old screenshot you provided. Your issue is that you have a broken MultiIndex on the columns, which happens when your columns are tuples with no second element: `MultiIndex([(   'country',), (    'Energy',), ...])`. Fix it with `df.columns=[x[0] for x in df.columns]`

Comment: @ALollz thanks. broken Multindex on the columns was the problem. It now works after running the code you provided.